# Rabbitmq on high load: Socket.error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, sockets, rabbitmq, celery

I have been using celery with rabbitmq as backend. Whenever I send a high load (around 600-1000) tasks to rabbitmq, I get following error
socket.error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

A sample command which I have been using is:

```
for i in {1..500}; do python client.py queue_name time_out bash -c "sleep 20 && touch folder/$i" & done
for i in {1..500}; do python client.py different_queue_name time_out bash -c "sleep 20 && touch folder/$i" & done
```

Here client.py sends a task which executes the given bash command at worker and polls the result for time_out seconds.

I also tried sending load over an interval of time using this command. It still gives the same error

```
for i in {1..10}; do for i in {1..50}; do python client.py queue_name time_out bash -c "sleep 60 && touch folder/$i" & done; sleep 10; done
for i in {1..10}; do for i in {1..50}; do python client.py different_queue_name time_out bash -c "sleep 60 && touch folder/$i" & done; sleep 10; done
```

What is causing this behaviour and what can I do to handle this situation?

Comment: did you check the logs?

Comment: This is the warning I am facing.
=WARNING REPORT==
file descriptor limit alarm set. Is file descriptor not freed once the message is delivered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=WARNING REPORT== file descriptor limit alarm set.` means that your reach the filedescriptor limit.

You should tuning your O.S. and RabbitMQ.

Here a few link you should follow:

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/production-checklist.html

> Open File Handles Limit Operating systems limit maximum number of
>   concurrently open file handles, which includes network sockets. Make
>   sure that you have limits set high enough to allow for expected number
>   of concurrent connections and queues.
>
> Make sure your environment allows for at least 50K open file
>   descriptors for effective RabbitMQ user, including in development
>   environments.
>
> As a rule of thumb, multiple the 95th percentile number of concurrent
>   connections by 2 and add total number of queues to calculate
>   recommended open file handle limit. Values as high as 500K are not
>   inadequate and won't consume a lot of hardware resources, and
>   therefore are recommended for production setups. See Networking guide
>   for more information.

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html

> Erlang VM I/O Thread Pool Erlang runtime uses a pool of threads for
>   performing I/O operations asynchronously. The size of the pool is
>   configured via the +A VM command line flag, e.g. +A 128. We highly
>   recommend overriding the flag using the
>   `RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS` environment variable:
>
> RABBITMQ_SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="+A 128" Default value is 30.
>   Nodes that have 8 or more cores available are recommended to use
>   values higher than 96, that is, 12 or more I/O threads for every core
>   available. Note that higher values do not necessarily mean better
>   throughput or lower CPU burn due to waiting on I/O. Tuning for a Large
>   Number of Connections
>
> Some workloads, often referred to as "the Internet of Things", assume
>   a large number of client connections per node, and a relatively low
>   volume of traffic from each node. One such workload is sensor
>   networks: there can be hundreds of thousands or millions of sensors
>   deployed, each emitting data every several minutes. Optimising for the
>   maximum number of concurrent clients can be more important than for
>   total throughput.
>
> Several factors can limit how many concurrent connections a single
>   node can support:
>
> Number of open file handles (including sockets) Amount of RAM used by
>   each connection Amount of CPU resources used by each connection

Hope it helps